# How can I fix "Field 'createdAt' doesn't have a default value" error?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do a migration on a long running project in which many migrations like this have been done. But suddenly it does not let me insert some values in a new table I just created in the previous migration.

It throws:
**ERROR:** Field 'createdAt' doesn't have a default value

But in all previous migrations that create tables I just set it up without default value, just setting timestamps in the model's init.

The code that creates the table looks like this (names changed just for this question):

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('testTable', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      testColumn: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    })
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('testTable')
  }
}
```

And the next seed that inserts the two fields I want:

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('testTable', [
      { testColumn: 'test1' },
      { testColumn: 'test2' }
    ])
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete(
      'testTable',
      {
        testColumn: {
          [Sequelize.Op.Or]: [
            { [Sequelize.Op.Like]: 'test1' },
            { [Sequelize.Op.Like]: 'test2' }
          ]
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

I have also init the model with timestamps set to true:

```
  TestTable.init({
    testColumn: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: true,
    updatedAt: false,
    modelName: 'testTable'
  })
```

Comment: It's obvious - set default value to this column in the table structure. `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` recommended.

Comment: I prefer not to modify the default value in the DB because Sequelize takes care of that already, it was just for the seeds/migrations that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I didn't read the docs thoroughly as it was implicitly explained on some block of code [on this page](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#creating-the-first-seed):

```
    module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: 'example@example.com',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }]);
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
  }
};
```

It seems that Sequelize takes care of the timestamps (createdAt/updatedAt) when using the ORM directly but not on migrations/seeds. That's why it needs to be set up explicitly.